# Is `*` (the asterisk) a keyword in C11?

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer, c11

In section 6.4.1 of the C11 standard an asterisk appears in the list of keywords:

```
keyword: one of
  auto      ∗ if        unsigned
  break       inline    void
  ...
```

Does this indicate that `*` is a keyword?

If not, what is its use here indicating?

Comment: It is not a keyword, but an overloaded operator.

Comment: @leeduhem The question refers to the C 11 specification, not the C++ 11 specification.

Comment: @JefferyThomas In C, `*` also have several functions, in other words, it is a builtin overloaded operator.

Comment: @leeduhem: In lexical terms, though, it is a punctuator (6.4.6)

Comment: @rici Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a diff mark.

In the abstract (p.1) of [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Changes from the previous draft (N1539) are indicated by ‘‘diff marks’’ in the right
>   margin: deleted text is marked with ‘‘∗’’, new or changed text with ‘‘ ’’.

In the [N1539](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1539.pdf) draft, `alignof` was a keyword, appearing on the first row of that table:

[N1750](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) dropped `alignof` and replaced it with `_Alignof`.

The placement of the "*" does seem slightly odd, but it definitely doesn't refer to the `*` operator.

Comment: Why does it appear next to `if`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for your improvement.